# Speed difference in write to socket on slow and fast connections?

Tags: java, sockets, stream

Does a write to a plain Outputstream backed by a java socket (on serverside) take the same time to clients with a fast and slow connection?

I would suspect no, but i can also suspect that there is some kind of buffer in front of the socket internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two socket buffers. One for output, one for input. If you're writing data that fits in the buffers, the speed of the connection doesn't matter *for the first write*.

After that there will be a noticeable difference, and the slow connection will block a lot more, waiting for space in the output buffer. Of course that speed difference won't affect the code, you'll just be writing data that eventually will be transferred, whether it happens fast or slow. It's only the end user that notices the slowness.

Comment: Cheers @Kayaman for the clear explanation! Wouldn't you notice the speed difference when you have a server which receives data on 1 socket and sends it directly to other clients. Then 1 slow client will increase the time it takes for the received data to be send to all clients. I suspect that this means i have to decouple the "receiving of data" and the "sending data to clients"?

Comment: No, you would have (in basic blocking IO) a separate thread responsible for communicating with each client. It would not affect other clients at all. Those threads could then have their own buffers for messages, depending on your design.